# Retain errorBody from HttpException

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to map the error body from an exception into into a useful model with now luck, using moshi and retrofit 2.9.0

I found numerous posts discussing the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me.

My code is the following

```
private fun getErrorMessageFromGenericResponse(httpException: HttpException): String? {
    var errorMessage: String? = null
    try {
        val body = httpException.response()!!.errorBody()!!
        val errorResponse = body.string().toObject(ErrorResponse::class.java)
        errorMessage = errorResponse?.message
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        return errorMessage
    }
}

fun <T> String.toObject(objectClass: Class<T>): T? {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val adapter = moshi.adapter(objectClass).lenient()
    return adapter.fromJson(this)
}
```

I tried also using this but it also does not work:

```
httpException.response()!!.errorBody()!!.source().buffer.snapshot().utf8()
```

I am probably missing something really simple as I think its a common usecase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun handleErrorResponse(e: Throwable): String {

    return when (e) {
        is HttpException -> {
            parseHTTPError(e.response()!!.errorBody())
        }

        is SocketTimeoutException -> {
            ApiConstants.TIME_OUT
        }

        is IOException -> {
            ApiConstants.SERVERERROR
        }
        else -> ApiConstants.SERVERERROR
    }
}

fun parseHTTPError(responseBody: ResponseBody?): String {
    try {
        val jsonObject=JSONObject(responseBody!!.string())
        try {
            val error=jsonObject.getJSONArray("message")
            return error[0].toString()
        }
```

catch (ex: Exception) {
responseBody!!.close()
return ""
}
responseBody.close()
return ""
}

Comment: Nice one!! But why use `jsonObject.getJSONArray("message")` when you can easily get the error message by simply calling `jsonObject.getString("message")`?